# Create seaprate SAS result window for separate proc tabulate

Tags: sas

Issue: I'm running in the same code two separate proc tabulate which generate two seaparate cross frequency tables. I would be able to generate two different result reports as output instead of the standard one aggregating the two outputs in the same result page, without the need to create two separate codes. There is any method to achive this?

Update1 : Below is the output of the two proc tabulate I want separate into two differente objects.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E0vzG.png)

Comment: Are you running your sas code in batch, SAS Studio, DI Studio or Enterprise Guide?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the SAS [ODS](https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63962/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_ods_sect001.htm) (Output Delivery System) and output your results to two different files. (the file can be a pdf, html, rtf).

Code below based on SAS Support [Example](https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63962/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_ods_sect010.htm) will split the output into two files ttest1.htm & ttest2.htm

```
title 'Comparing Group Means';

data Scores;
   input Gender $ Score @@;
   datalines;
f 75  f 76  f 80  f 77  f 80  f 77  f 73
m 82  m 80  m 85  m 85  m 78  m 87  m 82
;
ods html body='ttest1.htm' style=HTMLBlue;
proc ttest;
   class Gender;
   var Score;
run;
ods html close;
ods html body='ttest2.htm' style=HTMLBlue;
proc ttest;
   class Gender;
   var Score;
run;
ods html close;
```

**In SAS Enterprise Guide:**

You can add the option to create your SAS report output in RTF and PDF formats. This will show the page break in one file/report.
Go to Tools/Options then check the output formats you want and re-run your project.

[image: EG Options]

Comment: Hi MomoI'm using Enterprise guide, coding within it. Your suggestion create two different html files, BUT I need the same format as a SAS report, as these two output in the end get aggregate in a SAS EG report.

Comment: When you run this code in EG you will see an extra tab containing the html files created, you may need to click download to show the files contents.

Comment: Yes I see the html. And I cna download them. But the issue is that these files can't be aggregated to the SAS EG report they are supposed to be destinated for. Also, I'm not an experte on it, but the proc tabulate standard result seems of a different format than the html files created with the ods. And as said only the first is accepted in the sas report

Comment: I added in my answer more options in EG which may solve the issue, try and let me know if ti worked for you.